# SQL QUERY disturbing Error

Tags: sql

I have to write a query which displays the First and Last Name for all users who belong to the Role “Lumo Advantage”.

I wrote it as:

```
SELECT Users.FirstName, Users.LastName
INNER JOIN Users
ON UserRoles.UserID = Users.UserID
WHERE UserRoles.RoleID =7;
```

But it is showing error. why? Kindly point out the mistake.

[image]

Comment: What is the error and why is it so disturbing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps because you left out a `from` clause:

```
SELECT Users.FirstName, Users.LastName
FROM Users INNER JOIN
     UserRoles
     ON UserRoles.UserID = Users.UserID
WHERE UserRoles.RoleID = 7;
```

I would suggest you learn to use table aliases . . . so queries are easier to write and to read:

```
SELECT u.FirstName, u.LastName
FROM Users u INNER JOIN
     UserRoles ur
     ON ur.UserID = u.UserID
WHERE ur.RoleID = 7;
```

Comment: :I also had to write a query which displays the First and Last Name in a single column, for all users that don’t have a Role. I did it this way but the automated checker marked this one also as incorrect. Despite thinking for several hours, I couldn't get any error... is there any?

SELECT CONCAT (FirstName, ' ' , LastName) AS `FullName`
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN UserRoles ON
UserRoles.UserId = Users.UserId
WHERE UserRoles.UserId Is NULL

Comment: The question in your comment is very different from the question you have asked.  If you have another question, you should ask it as a question.  That said, your query looks quite reasonable, assuming you are using a database that support `concat()`.

Comment: oops! I didn't read if the database supported concat or not!! :(

Comment: Lindoff - Thanks a lot! The forum allows to post only 1 question every 90 minutes so I am putting here in the comments.

But I have one more confusion.

I had to write a query which lists all the Roles and how many users below (belong) to each role where the Role has less than 20 users in it.

It did like this:

SELECT
*
FROM
(
SELECT
Roles.RoleName,
(
SELECT
COUNT (*)
FROM
UserRoles
WHERE
UserRoles.RoleID = Roles.RoleID
) AS User_Count
FROM
Roles
)
WHERE
User_Count <20

Despite that the automated checker marked this one in red. I simply cannot understand what went wrong. Kindly explain.

Comment: The right approach uses `group by` and a `having` clause.

Comment: I still could not understand. kindly elaborate. What would be your response?